# Rate your programming language expertise by language concepts

Tags: programming-languages, interview

I am looking for a good way to **rate the expertise** in a particular **programming language**. The idea arose when I found the following article: [Taking falsely all the credits? You don't know JavaScript](http://www.w2lessons.com/2011/04/you-dont-know-javascript.html). It lists, in a comprehensive way, **language features and concepts** of JavaScript. I wish there would be a list for every programming language. In particular I would be interested about:

- Java
- C
- Python
- C# / [.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhatGreatNETDevelopersOughtToKnowMoreNETInterviewQuestions.aspx)
- C++
- [JavaScript](http://www.w2lessons.com/2011/04/you-dont-know-javascript.html)

Any other language or technology would be also interesting. In a similiar question [What's a good way to rate your own code skills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384289/whats-a-good-way-to-rate-your-own-coding-skill) the [Programmer Competency Matrix](http://www.indiangeek.net/wp-content/uploads/Programmer%20competency%20matrix.htm) was suggested. I think it's a good approach, but I think it's too generic.

Do you know any other summaries of language concepts which could help to rate the programming language expertise?

Comment: Probably nothing better than the Programmer Competency Matrix, but there could be language / language family / paradigm specific equivalents out there. The question might be interpreted by some as asking for a list of stuff, which is generally discouraged, but that highly depends on the answers, let's hope answerers keep it clean and constructive. +1 for a very interesting question, hopefully also an on topic one...

Comment: looks like you linked to SO x2, can you repost the link to "Taking falsely all the credits?"

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks for the hint, just updated the link

Comment: Not language specific, but a very interesting and related read: http://www.yacoset.com/Home/signs-that-you-re-a-bad-programmer

Comment: @platzhirsch Why the competency matrix is generic:  Once your more-concrete list is complete, I'll just go and learn the most complex thing for each language and ignore the rest.  Does that make me an expert?  ;)

Comment: It is difficult to make such a matrix. Also, sometimes you cannot evaluate the skills of a developer just by looking at how many concepts of a programming language he / she knows: I prefer a developer that uses only a subset of a language but writes clean code to a developer who writes unnecessarily complicated code just to show that he / she knows how to use a certain feature of the language. This might seem strange but I have seen such cases.

Comment: @Giorgio yes, you argument is very reasonable, such a matirx cannot be used for a total evaluation of your actual skills

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For evaluating the .Net Programming expertise, Scott Hanselman's gives guidelines on the know-how required for various positions in a .Net Development Scenario.**

> - Everyone who writes code
> - Mid-Level .NET Developer Senior
> - Developers/Architects
> - C# Component Developers
> - ASP.NET (UI) Developers
> - Developers using XML

**The knowledge acquired from these questionnaires would definitely help overcome obstacles.**

[Please find the details explained here.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhatGreatNETDevelopersOughtToKnowMoreNETInterviewQuestions.aspx)